# Previous DAX value grouped by quarter number and name

Tags: group-by, powerbi, dax

In my current dataset I have a "Target" set for a "Quarter" for each "Name". The "Target" is only present against the first week in the quarter however.

Therefore when I use a date slicer I cannot see the quarter target.

[image]

The above carries on up until the next quarter when the target is present again and 0 for each week after that.

I believe the solution would be to amend each "Target" to be the same value as the first value grouped by the "Name" and "Quarter".

I have created a new measure and attempted this using the EARLIER and GROUPBY functions but am not able to bring this together.

I would very much appreciate any help or guidance on this.

Thanks

Will

Comment: Wouldn't it be more sensible to perform this operation within Power Query?

Comment: Hi @JosWoolley I've tried it both ways and come up short I'm afraid. I'd be happy to tackle it either way. Can you advise how I would go about this in Power Query?

Comment: So you'd want to keep the original Target column but then perhaps have a new column which generates your required values?

Comment: Yes, I'd be more than happy to have an additional column which has the same number of the initial week so long as it was split by quarter and name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since looking at this I have been able to manipulate the data with DAX. Using a combination of base DAX measure and an all except filter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is derived from a query named `Table1` within Power Query:

1. Duplicate that query and name this new query `Table2`
2. In the `Table2` query, filter out rows for which the `Target` entry is zero
3. Select the `Table1` query and `Merge Queries` (**not** `As New`) on the `Table1` and `Table2` queries, selecting the `Name` and `Quarter` columns in each table, `Left Outer` join
4. Expand the new `Table2` column (checking only the `Target` column for the expansion)
5. Rename this new column as required

Comment: Hi Jos, unfortunately this throws out all other calculations from that table.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "throws out all other calculations"?

Comment: When I merge everything all the other calculations are increased by a large amount.

Since looking at this I have been able to manipulate the data with DAX. Using a combination of base DAX measure and an all except filter.

I really appreciate your time